# QML Mouse areas are affected in separate zones

Tags: qml, qt6

I created a frameless `Window` in `QML` and added multiple `MouseArea` and event handlers for moving and resizing it.
Initially, I only created the *moving area* and part of the *resizing areas* as a sample.

However, when I started, I noticed that events were only triggered for 3 out of the 4 areas, and they appeared to be intersecting despite not overlapping.
The cursor also changed in the correct place.

This problem occurred on both *Linux* and *Windows*.

What could be the reason for the active zones of different `MouseArea` intersecting, even though they should not?

To debug, I added a colored `Rectangle`s for each `MouseArea` and increased their sizes."

I have also uploaded a [**sample video**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jSiZvxBE4EjbDjBg-GPPflxdTnULSlYA/view?usp=sharing) on Google Drive.

#### MyWin.qml

```
import QtQuick 6.2
import QtQuick.Controls 6.2

Window {
    id: win
    width: 200
    height: 100
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window
    property alias topPanel: topPanel

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#610161"

        Rectangle {
            id: topPanel
            z: 0
            height: 30
            color: "#4c4c4c"
            border.width: 0
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 0

            ActionButton {
                id: close
                width: 20
                height: 20
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.top: parent.top
                z: 10
                image: "icons/close.svg"
                anchors.topMargin: 5
                anchors.rightMargin: 5
                backColor: "#00000000"

                Connections {
                    function onClicked() {
                        win.close()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: moved
            z: 2

            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                z: 32
                color: "#6a30e4"
            }

            property real lastX: 0
            property real lastY: 0
            x: 35
            y: 0
            anchors.left: lt.right
            anchors.right: topPanel.right
            anchors.top: topPanel.top
            anchors.bottom: topPanel.bottom
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 0
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            Connections {
                target: moved
                function onPressed(mouse) {
                    console.debug("Pressed move", mouse.x, mouse.y, "MOVED:",
                                  moved.x, moved.y, "|", moved.width, "x",
                                  moved.height)
                    moved.lastX = mouse.x
                    moved.lastY = mouse.y
                    mouse.accepted = true
                }
                function onPositionChanged(mouse) {
                    mouse.accepted = true
                    let dx = (mouse.x - moved.lastX)
                    let dy = (mouse.y - moved.lastY)
                    console.debug("move dx:", dx, " dy:", dy, " mouse:",
                                  mouse.x, mouse.y, mouse.modifiers)
                    win.x += dx
                    win.y += dy
                }
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: lbord
            z: 2
            width: 5
            anchors.top: lt.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.bottom: lb.top
            anchors.topMargin: 0

            Rectangle {
                color: "#43ca28"
                anchors.fill: parent
                z: 32
            }
            property real lastX: 0
            property real lastY: 0
            Connections {
                target: lbord
                function onPressed(mouse) {
                    console.debug("Pressed lbord")
                    lbord.lastX = mouse.x
                }
                function onPositionChanged(mouse) {
                    let dx = (mouse.x - lbord.lastX)
                    console.debug("lbord dx:", dx, " lastX:", lbord.lastX,
                                  " mouse:", mouse.x, mouse.y)
                    win.x += dx
                    win.width -= dx
                    //                    lbord.lastX += dx
                }
            }
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: lb
            z: 2
            width: 15
            height: 15
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            Rectangle {
                color: "#28cac7"
                anchors.fill: parent
                z: 32
            }

            property real lastX: 0
            property real lastY: 0
            Connections {
                target: moved
                function onPressed(mouse) {
                    console.debug("Pressed lb", mouse.x, mouse.y, "LB:", lb.x,
                                  lb.y, "|", lb.width, "x", lb.height)
                    lb.lastX = mouse.x
                    lb.lastY = mouse.y
                }
                function onPositionChanged(mouse) {
                    let dx = (mouse.x - lb.lastX)
                    let dy = (mouse.y - lb.lastY)
                    console.debug("lb dx:", dx, " dy:", dy, " mouse:", mouse.x,
                                  mouse.y, mouse.modifiers)
                    win.x += dx
                    win.y += dy
                    win.width -= dx
                    win.height += dy
                }
            }
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: lt
            z: 2
            width: 35
            height: 35
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            cursorShape: Qt.SizeFDiagCursor
            Rectangle {
                color: "#eb1892"
                anchors.fill: parent
                z: 32
            }

            property real lastX: 0
            property real lastY: 0
            Connections {
                target: moved
                function onPressed(mouse) {
                    console.debug("Pressed lt", mouse.x, mouse.y, "LT:", lt.x,
                                  lt.y, "|", lt.width, "x", lt.height)
                    lt.lastX = mouse.x
                    lt.lastY = mouse.y
                }
                function onPositionChanged(mouse) {
                    let dx = (mouse.x - lt.lastX)
                    let dy = (mouse.y - lt.lastY)
                    console.debug("lt dx:", dx, " dy:", dy, " mouse:", mouse.x,
                                  mouse.y, mouse.modifiers)
                    win.x += dx
                    win.y += dy
                    win.width -= dx
                    win.height -= dy
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> A video showing the bugs [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jSiZvxBE4EjbDjBg-GPPflxdTnULSlYA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi, for a frameless window, please refer to this answer: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74166152/11603485).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You signal handler function are triggered in 3 out of 4 of your `Connections` objects because you assigned the same `target` for 3 of them.

You don't even have to use `Connections` since you are the one instantiating your `MouseArea`:

```
MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea
    Connections {
        target: mouseArea
        function onPressed(mouse) { ... }
    }
}
```

Is the equivalent of

```
MouseArea {
    onPressed(mouse) { ... }
}
```

Also I would advise to use [startSystemMove](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwindow.html#startSystemMove) and [startSystemResize](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwindow.html#startSystemResize).

Comment: Thank you, I removed the explicit bindings to target and everything worked as it should. And the functions also made it possible to reduce the necessary code.