window flickering when resizing QML
The application window flickers when I change its size

part of the code responsible for resizing
        MouseArea { // изменение размера top
        width: parent.width
        height: 2

        cursorShape: Qt.SizeVerCursor

        onPressed: {
            mainWindow.previousY = mouseY
        }

        onPositionChanged: {
            mainWindow.setHeight(mainWindow.height - (mouseY - mainWindow.previousY))
        }
    }

full code
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import "../resources/"

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint // Отключение стандартного обрамления окна

    property int previousX // переменная хранящая X зажатого курсора
    property int previousY // переменная хранящая Y зажатого курсора

    readonly property real toolBarHeight: toolBar.height // переменная хранящая размер toolBar

    readonly property real maxWidthSize: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth // переменная хранящая максимальную ширина окна
    readonly property real maxHeightSize: Screen.desktopAvailableHeight // переменная хранящая максимальную длину окна

    property real lastWidthSize: 640 // переменная хранящая последнюю не максимальную ширина окна
    property real lastHeightSize: 480 // переменная хранящая последнюю не максимальную длину окна

    property real lastWindowX: mainWindow.x // переменная хранящая последее положение окна по X
    property real lastWindowY: mainWindow.y // переменная хранящая последнее положение окна по Y

    Rectangle {
        id: toolBar
        width: parent.width
        height: 34
        color: Colors.toolBarColor

        MouseArea { // перемещение окна
            anchors.fill: parent

            onPressed: {
                mainWindow.previousX = mouseX
                mainWindow.previousY = mouseY
            }

            onDoubleClicked: {
                if(mainWindow.maxWidthSize == mainWindow.width && mainWindow.maxHeightSize == mainWindow.height)
                {
                    mainWindow.setWidth(mainWindow.lastWidthSize)
                    mainWindow.setHeight(mainWindow.lastHeightSize)
                    mainWindow.setX(mainWindow.lastWindowX)
                    mainWindow.setY(mainWindow.lastWindowY)
                }
                else
                {
                    mainWindow.setWidth(mainWindow.maxWidthSize)
                    mainWindow.setHeight(mainWindow.maxHeightSize)
                }
            }

            onPositionChanged: {
                mainWindow.setX(mainWindow.x + (mouseX - mainWindow.previousX))
                mainWindow.setY(mainWindow.y + (mouseY - mainWindow.previousY))
                mainWindow.lastWindowX = mainWindow.x
                mainWindow.lastWindowY = mainWindow.y
            }
        }

        MouseArea { // изменение размера top
            width: parent.width
            height: 2

            cursorShape: Qt.SizeVerCursor

            onPressed: {
                mainWindow.previousY = mouseY
            }

            onPositionChanged: {
                mainWindow.setHeight(mainWindow.height - (mouseY - mainWindow.previousY))
            }
        }
    }
}

when I change the measurement by double-clicking (upper MouseArea) I don’t notice such problems, I think the problem is that the application is redrawn all the time when the size is changed, can this be fixed somehow?
OC Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

Try using startSystemResize.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74166152/11603485
